# Pivoting SQL Server 2008 Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have created the following query in SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT dimUser.EmpFName, dimUser.EmpLName, dimUser.EmpStartDt, dimUser.MgrEmpFullName1, 
    dimUser.PrimaryJobName, dimUser.PrimaryOrgName, Org.Org_Name
FROM dimUser 
INNER JOIN tblEmpOrg AS fact 
  ON dimUser.ID = fact.EmpOrg_EmpFK 
INNER JOIN Org 
  ON fact.EmpOrg_OrgFK = Org.Org_PK
```

The data produces multiple rows as there are many different org names per user.

```
Employee Name  Manager Name          Org_Name
Neil Jones     Elizabeth O'Donnell   USA 
Neil Jones     Elizabeth O'Donnell   AFG 
Neil Jones     Elizabeth O'Donnell   USA REG A
```

How do I pivot this query to produce multiple columns for the different organisations. I.E. Org 1, Org 2, Org 3 etc.

```
Employee Name  Manager Name         Org_NAME 1  Org_Name 2  Org_Name 3
Neil Jones     Elizabeth O'Donnell  USA         AFG         USA REG A
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to transform the data. However, you will want to apply `row_number()` to each employee to help in turning the row data into columns.

If you have a known number of values for each employee, then you can hard-code the query similar to this:

```
select [Employee Name],
  [Manager Name],
  Org_Name_1, 
  Org_Name_2, 
  Org_Name_3
from
(
  select [Employee Name], [Manager Name], [Org_Name],
    'Org_Name_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [Employee Name] order by [Employee Name]) as varchar(50)) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max([Org_Name])
  for rn in (Org_Name_1, Org_Name_2, Org_Name_3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d255a/2)

But if you have an unknown number of `org_name` values per employee, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(rn) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'Org_Name_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [Employee Name] order by [Employee Name]) as varchar(50)) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Employee Name], [Manager Name],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [Employee Name], [Manager Name], [Org_Name],
                  ''Org_Name_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by [Employee Name] order by [Employee Name]) as varchar(50)) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Org_Name)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c2a3/1)

Both generate the result:

```
| EMPLOYEE NAME |        MANAGER NAME | ORG_NAME_1 | ORG_NAME_2 | ORG_NAME_3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Neil Jones | Elizabeth O'Donnell |        USA |        AFG |  USA REG A |
```

*Note: replace the `yourtable` with your query*

Comment: @user2018015 can you expand on that?  Do you get an error? Can you edit the sql fiddle with your tables and some data?

Comment: select [EmpFullName1],
  [MgrEmpFullName1],
  Org_Name_1, 
  Org_Name_2, 
  Org_Name_3
from
(
  select [EmpFullName1], [MgrEmpFullName1], [Org_Name],
    'Org_Name_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [EmpFullName1] order by [EmpFullName1]) as varchar(50)) rn
  from  dimUser INNER JOIN
                      tblEmpOrg AS FACT ON dimUser.EmpFK = FACT.EmpOrg_EmpFK INNER JOIN
                      Org ON FACT.EmpOrg_OrgFK = Org.Org_PK
) src
pivot
(
  max([Org_Name])
  for rn in (Org_Name_1, Org_Name_2, Org_Name_3)
) piv

Comment: @user2018015 you need to be a lot more specific if you want real help.

Comment: @user2018015 I am having a hard time helping you since you are not giving enough details.  If you run the subquery prior to the pivot does it work?

Comment: @bluefeet The dynamic solution works for me.

Question - Where would you use ISNULL() to replace NULLs with '' in the ORG_NAME columns?

Comment: @kevro If you need to replace the null values, then you will create two lists of columns. See this answer of mine -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150068/sql-using-isnull-with-dynamic-pivot/15156448#15156448